# 7-segment display with hex output

Tags: verilog, quartus

I am trying to utilize a 7-segment display. I have written a module which I want to take 4 inputs and change the hex output. There seems to be an issue with unpacked/packed arrays. Any help is appreciated.

```
module hexDisplay (hex, c0, c1, c2, c3);
    input c0;
    input c1;
    input c2;
    input c3;      
    output hex [6:0];       
    reg out [6:0];
 
    always@(*)
    begin
        case({c3, c2, c1, c0})
            4'b0000:out [5:0] = 1;
            // 0001-1111 go here
            //...
            default:out [6:0] = 0;
         endcase
      assign hex = out;
     end
endmodule
```

Errors:

> Error (10773): Verilog HDL error at lab2pre.v(55): declaring module ports or function arguments with unpacked array types requires SystemVerilog extensions
> Error (10133): Verilog HDL Expression error at lab2pre.v(61): illegal part select of unpacked array "out"

> Error (10133): Verilog HDL Expression error at lab2pre.v(62): illegal part select of unpacked array "out"

> Error (10048): Verilog HDL error at lab2pre.v(64): values cannot be assigned directly to all or part of array "hex" - assignments must be made to individual elements only

> Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at lab2pre.v(64): object "hex" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type

> Error (10044): Verilog HDL error at lab2pre.v(64): expression cannot reference entire array "out"

> Error: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 6 errors, 1 warning
> Error: Peak virtual memory: 959 megabytes
> Error: Processing ended: Tue Feb  2 17:33:35 2016
> Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:15
> Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:46

> Error (293001): Quartus II Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 8 errors, 1 warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Errors :

- You need to have "packed" array rather than an "unpacked" array for
  "out" & "hex" nets.

  > SystemVerilog supports both packed arrays and unpacked arrays of data.
  >   The term packed array is used to refer to the dimensions declared
  >   before the data identifier name. The term unpacked array is used to
  >   refer to the dimensions declared after the data identifier name.

  bit [7:0] c1; // packed array of scalar bit types
     real u [7:0]; // unpacked array of real types

  > A packed array is a mechanism for subdividing a vector into subfields,
  >   which can be conveniently accessed as array elements. Consequently, a
  >   packed array is guaranteed to be represented as a contiguous set of
  >   bits.
  >
  > An unpacked array may or may not be so represented. A packed array
  >   differs from an unpacked array in that, when a packed array appears as
  >   a primary, it is treated as a single vector.

  So in the code, you require, **out & hex** to be used as a continuous
  bit vector, then it **should be packed array**, instead of unpacked
  array.

  Refer to topic 7.4 of the Systemverilog LRM.
- assign statement to hex, cannot be with in always block. Because an
  assign statement is used for modeling only combinational logic and it
  is executed continuously. So the assign statement is called
  'continuous assignment statement' as there is no sensitive list.

  So it can't be within always block, which is executed as per
  sensitivity list.

So your final working code is as below:

```
module hexDisplay(hex, c0, c1, c2, c3);
    input c0;
    input c1;
    input c2;
    input c3;      
    output [6:0] hex;       
    reg [6:0] out;

    always@(*)
    begin
        case({c3, c2, c1, c0})
            4'b0000:out [5:0] = 1;
            // 0001-1111 go here
            //...
            default:out [6:0] = 0;
         endcase
     end

    assign hex = out;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.  Move the range specifiers (`[6:0]`) to the left of the signal names, and move the `assign` outside of the `always` block.

```
module hexDisplay(hex, c0, c1, c2, c3);
    input c0;
    input c1;
    input c2;
    input c3;      
    output [6:0] hex;
    reg [6:0] out;

    always@(*)
    begin
        case({c3, c2, c1, c0})
            4'b0000:out [5:0] = 1;
            // 0001-1111 go here
            //...
            default:out [6:0] = 0;
         endcase
     end
     assign hex = out;

endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

whatever variable in always block must be reg , here you assign hex in always which is by default wire  so if you assign hex at out side of always u will get compile free code.

Comment: I've since solved my issue, but I'm interested in what you're getting at as I want to learn more about verilog. As I understand a wire can only hold 1 value, but here when I declare `hex` I assign it 7 indices(not sure what the true term is). What does `output [6:0] hex;` really do?

Also, am I not assigning `hex` outside of my always block? Could I just forget about my `hex` variable and do something like `output reg [6:0] hex;`?